# Recursive Predicate continues after reaching the base case

Tags: recursion, prolog

I am trying to write a predicate called 'range' that creates a list of ints in the specified range.

Example:

```
range(4,9, L).
L = [4,5,6,7,8,9]
```

The predicate I have written seems to be working correctly but when it finishes I have the ability to hit "Next" and then it returns:

> L = [4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, _1200|_1202]

Here is my code:

```
range(Low, Low, [Low]). %base case, if low and high are equal 
range(Low, High, [H|T]):-
    Low > High,
    !;          %if low is greater than high cut
    H is Low,   %set the head of the list
    Num is Low + 1, %increment low by 1
    range(Num, High, T).    %recursive call
```

I also want it to return an empty list if an invalid range is given. For example:

> range(10, 4, L).

should return an empty list. Instead I am getting:

> L = [_1164|_1166]

How can I adjust this so that it returns an empty list rather than (what I assume to be) addresses for the head and tail.

Here is what it looks like when I trace through:

[image: Trace]

Comment: You wrote a semi-colon instead of a comma at the cut, but the cut is useless anyway.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could simplify the control flow, for instance

```
range(Low, Low, [Low]). %base case, if low and high are equal
range(Low, High, [Low|T]):- %set the head of the list
    Low < High,
    Num is Low + 1, %increment low by 1
    range(Num, High, T).    %build the tail
```

Now the second clause will cover only the intended case.

About your solution, when the `Low>High` condition *succeeds*, the cut *succeeds* also, and variables in `[H|T]` don't get any bindings (remains uninstantiated), while the clause succeeds as well. A fix would force the rule failure:

```
range(Low, Low, [Low]). %base case, if low and high are equal
range(Low, High, [H|T]):- %set the head of the list
    Low > High,
    !, fail; % force failure
    H is Low,
    Num is Low + 1, %increment low by 1
    range(Num, High, T).    %recursive call
```

but this will leave an useless choicepoint for each element computed.

*edit*

Here is a possibility to get an empty list for your requirements:

```
range(Low, High, R):-
    (   Low > High
    ->  R = []
    ;   R = [Low|T],
        Num is Low + 1,
        range(Num, High, T)
    ).
```

Note I dropped the first clause (base recursion, now covered by the first branch), and used the easier to read '[if-then-else](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=(-%3E)/2)' construct. For our snippet, it's equivalent to this:

```
range(Low, High, R):-
    (   Low > High,
    !,  R = []
    ;   R = [Low|T],
        Num is Low + 1,
        range(Num, High, T)
    ).
```

Comment: Thank you for showing me how to simplify it. So when we force the failure is that why it returns "false" if I pass invalid parameters? Is there a way to get it so that it gives an empty list rather than false

Comment: Okay my only question then is what is stopping it from going on forever since there is no base case(that I see at least)? Say it gets to the Low > High when Low is 10 and High is 9. Does it then do the -> R = [] which just sets the tail of the list to an empty list?

Comment: Yes, the base clause is the first branch. Note that clauses containing `;` can be rewritten 'splitting' them around `;` in two clauses.

Answer (score 1):

You wrote a *semicolon* (`;`) after the cut (`!`) instead of a comma (`,`). A semicolon is, to some extent, equivalent to a "logical or", so you wrote something like:

```
range(A, A, [A]).
range(A, B, [C|E]) :-
    (   A>B, !
    ;   C is A,
        D is A+1,
        range(D, B, E)
    ).
```

For `range(1, 2, L)` there are basically two paths that yield a solution (this is no standard notation, it is only used here to give some insight in how Prolog obtains the results:

```
range(1, 2, [C|E])
    C is 1,
    D is 2,
    range(2, 2, E) :-
        range(2, 2, [2]).             % we found a solution
        range(2, 2, [C|E])
            C is 2,
            D is 3,
            range(3, 2, E) :-
                range(3, 2, [C|E])
                3 > 2.                 % we found a solution
```

The cut does *not* stop the execution of the clause, a cut means that Prolog will no longer consider the next clauses for that *specific* call (so if we perform recursion, the cut has no impact on the recursion itself). Since there are no other clauses, the cut here thus has no impact.

We can simplify the code to:

```
range(A, A, [A]).
range(A, B, [A|T]) :-
    A < B,
    A1 is A+1,
    range(A1, B, T).
```

Or we can use the [**`between/3`** [swi-doc]](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=between/3) builtin, and use a [**`findall/3`** [swi-doc]](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=findall/3) over this:

```
range(A, B, L) :-
    findall(X, between(A, B, X), L).
```

Comment: Thank you this helps a lot. I didn't fully understand what cut did but I get it now. When I run it with invalid parameters though I get a false instead of an empty list is there a way to make it so that it returns an empty list?

Comment: @Sauromayne: do you mean that `Start` is greater than `Stop`? The last solution with `between/3` should handle that.